# Why are my Ally Invest balances not displaying when everything was just working fine?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am quite new to Python and the `requests` module so I apologize if I am not expressing myself very well or if this is not the correct place to post this question.

Basically, I am trying to connect to my Ally Invest account using Python and `requests`. I have signed up for the API and have gotten the consumer key, secret, oauth token, and secret. I am currently trying to display my balances, with this as the first part of my code:

```
url = 'https://devapi.invest.ally.com/v1/accounts/{}/balances.json'.format(acct)

authorize = OAuth1(cKey, cSecret, oToken, oSecret)

my_acct = requests.get(url, auth = authorize)

my_acct.status_code
```

Everything looks fine and `my_acct.status_code` returns `200` but then I try running the following

```
data = my_acct.json()
data
```

and I get the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-2c5022dcbfa5> in <module>
----> 1 data = my_acct.json()
      2 data

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    895                     # used.
    896                     pass
--> 897         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    898 
    899     @property

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, use_decimal, **kw)
    516             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None
    517             and not use_decimal and not kw):
--> 518         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    519     if cls is None:
    520         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w, _PY3)
    368         if _PY3 and isinstance(s, bytes):
    369             s = str(s, self.encoding)
--> 370         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
    371         end = _w(s, end).end()
    372         if end != len(s):

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx, _w, _PY3)
    398             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
    399                 idx += 3
--> 400         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here is the output when I run `print(my_acct.text)`

```
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--[if IE]><html class="ie"><![endif]-->\n<!--[if !IE]><!-->\n<html>\n  <!--<![endif]-->\n\n  <head>\n    <meta charset="UTF-8" />\n    <meta\n      name="viewport"\n      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"\n    />\n    <meta\n      name="ROBOTS"\n      content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"\n    />\n    <meta\n      http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"\n      content="IE=edge"\n    />\n    <link\n      href="https://www.ally.com/failover/InvestSplash/faviconnewsplash.ico"\n      rel="shortcut icon"\n      type="image/x-icon"\n    />\n    <meta\n      name="format-detection"\n      content="telephone=no"\n    />\n    <title>We\'re sorry | Ally Bank</title>\n    <link\n      href="https://www.ally.com/failover/InvestSplash/core.buildnewsplash.css"\n      media="screen"\n      rel="stylesheet"\n      type="text/css"\n    />\n    <script\n      language="javascript"\n      type="text/javascript"\n      src="https://www.ally.com/failover/InvestSplash/jquery-1.4.2.js"\n    ></script>\n\n\n    <style type="text/css">\n      @font-face {\n        font-family: allycons;\n        src: url(\'https://www.ally.com/failover/InvestSplash/allyconsEOTnewsplash.eot\');\n        src: url(\'https://www.ally.com/failover/InvestSplash/allyconsEOTiefixnewsplash.eot\') format(\'embedded-opentype\'), url(\'https://www.ally.com/failover/InvestSplash/allyconsTTFnewsplash.ttf\') format(\'truetype\'), url(\'https://www.ally.com/failover/InvestSplash/allyconsWOFFnewsplash.woff\') format(\'woff\'), url(\'https://www.ally.com/failover/InvestSplash/allyconsSVGnewsplash.svg\') format(\'svg\');\n        font-weight: 400;\n        font-style: normal\n      }\n\n      [class*=" icon-"],\n      [class^=icon-] {\n        font-family: allycons !important;\n        speak: none;\n        font-style: normal;\n        font-weight: 400;\n        font-variant: normal;\n        text-transform: none;\n        line-height: 1;\n        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;\n        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: ... </body>\n\n</html>\n'
```

(Note: I've had to shorten it a bit, but this is the top part.)

The weird thing is, when I ran the above code block last night, it was working fine; showing a JSON of my balances. I tried looking up the error but have not found anything that seems to work.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `print(my_acct.text)` then paste the result here.

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: obviously the response is a html page. if you did got json last night using the same code, it could mean the website is either not stable enough or you credentials expired.

Comment: Oh ok. Any ideas on what I could do?

Comment: you should see enough information in that html(just save as html then open that in browser). you've omitted some text so we cannot know.

Comment: Thanks! I just did that and the webpage says 'Our site is unavailable right now. Check back with us later.' so I am assuming it's the website that's not working.

Comment: you can solve by some try catch. only parse real json.